# How to change duty cycle of $\sin()$ function

Tags: sequences-and-series, signal-processing

Is there a way to change the duty cycle of the sine function?

I am trying to use $\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(x))$ functions and I would love to change the width of pulses.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To squish to period of $\sin$ by a factor of $a$, turn $\sin(x)$ into $\sin(ax)$

Comment: @JoshuaWang That does not change the duty cycle.

Comment: The width can be changed, but any sinusoid has the same duty cycle!

Comment: @copper.hat yes. Also, I am not that good in English is there a better way to call **duty cycle**?

Comment: Probably you want to define a particular "rectangle" wave, and then compute its Fourier series.

Comment: Try $x \mapsto \operatorname{sgn} ( c+\sin x )$ for a constant $c$. (Only values $c \in [-1,1]$ are useful.)

Comment: @Simen Your English is fine, the term is not used much in mathematics, more engineering.

Comment: @copper.hat I will try! Also, thank you :-) I am an engineer more than a mathematician.

Comment: @copper.hat So I tried your formula and it is exactly what I needed. Thank you! :) Can you please write it as an answer and I will check it. Also, It would be great if you can elaborate a little bit more on why is $c∈[−1,1]$.

Comment: @Simen Glad to be able to help. If $c<-1$ then the output is always zero and similarly, if $c>1$ the output is always one.

Answer (score 0):

**Originally i thought you wanted to change the frequency of the function:**
Think about how the sine function is defined. If i put something in its argument i will get the sine of that thing. Now if i want the function to lengthen the function on the $x$-axis you need to put half of it to get the same function.

See: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkx76calgy

For a numerical example:
$$\sin\left(a\cdot\pi\right)=0$$

If i say:

$$\sin\left(\frac{b}{2}\pi\right)=0$$

$b$ needs to be twice the value of $a$ to get the same output. Essentially stretching the function sideways.

**Manipulating the duty cycle is a digital systems problem** and can be done formally easily in that manner. If you want to specifically calculate a specific function like that then the easiest but also the most tedious way to calculate it is to figure out your function between two oscillations and just take the Fourier series of it. But i don't think this is a very useful method for understanding the specific ratio.

Comment: This does not change the duty cycle, just the frequency.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad